# PHP/MySQL Conditional Insert Not Inserting

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get a quasi-conditional insert to work. I have three different types of elements in the database, and the created_at date is a unique key. The guy who built the database used the same structure for each table (lessons, series, packages), so I have to rely on the created_at filed for unique values.

The situation is that I want to insert a new row, but I don't know if it's in the purchased_lessons, purchased_series, or purchased_packages table. I know $item_current (that's the date return from $_POST - working in another section), and I know $user_id (same reason). But this is not inserting a new row:

```
$is_lesson = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM lessons WHERE created_at LIKE \"$item_current\""));
$is_series = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM series WHERE created_at LIKE \"$item_current\""));
$is_package = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM packages WHERE created_at LIKE \"$item_current\""));
$lesson_rows = mysql_num_rows($is_lesson);
$series_rows = mysql_num_rows($is_series);
$package_rows = mysql_num_rows($is_package);
$lesson_result = mysql_fetch_array($is_lesson);
$series_result = mysql_fetch_array($is_series);
$package_result = mysql_fetch_array($is_package);
$lesson_id_to_insert = $lesson_result['id'];
$series_id_to_insert = $series_result['id'];
$package_id_to_insert = $package_result['id'];

if ($lesson_rows > 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchased_lessons VALUES ($user_id,$lesson_id_to_insert])");
} else if ($series_rows > 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchased_series VALUES ($user_id,$series_id_to_insert)");
} else if ($package_rows > 0){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchased_packages VALUES ($user_id,$package_id_to_insert)");
}
```

I'm too close and can't see the forest for the trees, I guess. It just will not execute the insert.

Comment: echo out $lesson_rows $series_rows $package_rows

Comment: your escaping a result set?

Comment: `mysql_query` returns not a string, you can`t escape that. btw don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions

Comment: So where is your error handling? Whilst mysql_* functions are deprecated, that is what you show in your code, so try Checking the return value of mysql_query and display mysql_error() if it returns false

Comment: Thanks all. yes, maintaining an old system. Removed the escape string. The echo proposed by mnagel IS showing a value., ex 0 0 1 when it matches created_at from a package. None of the changes to the insert suggested below are working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchased_lessons VALUES (\"$user_id\",\"$lesson_id_to_insert\")");
```

In each insert query add the quotation mark.

Comment: there are many ways to put variables into strings, the best way is still the one suggested by Zend: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchased_lessons VALUES ('" . $user_id . "', '" . $lesson_id_to_insert . "')'");`

Comment: @DanFromGermany yes we can also do that. I know it. the main motto of mine is to tell that OP has missed the colons in the insert query.

Comment: In addition to removing mysql_real_escape_string, rewriting the query like this worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

On the top of your code is also incorrect change the following so you have `mysql_real_escape_string` out from the `mysql_query` return value.

```
$is_lesson = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM lessons WHERE created_at LIKE \"$item_current\""));
```

to read

```
$is_lesson = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM lessons WHERE created_at LIKE \"$item_current\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mysql_real_escape_string(....)
That is trying to escape a returned Resource handle, NOT NECESSARY and COULD BE CAUSING PROBLEMS to the later mysql_num_rows().

I wont bother with the warning about using the now deprecated mysql_* calls as its obvious you are maintaining an existing old system not written by you.